# MVC clickable ModelState error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to have a "clickable" model error message or put html, such as a `<div>` or `<a>` tag into a model error message?

After a form is submitted, I want to have the message that is returned be clickable text.

The message would be something like -

"The value for that field is invalid. Click **here** for suggestions".

I would then use JQuery to bind an "on click" event to the `<div>` or `<a>` tag.

This does not work -

```
 ModelState.AddModelError("Model.Property","<div>click this</div>");
```

It just displays the text -

```
 "<div>click this</div>"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you know what to do.  Where's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response cadrell0, I expanded my explanation. I want to do something like - ModelState.AddModelError("Model.Property","<div>click this</div>"); but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code below should do the trick even it's not the best one

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Property).ToHtmlString()))
```

**update**:

similar code for ValidationSummary:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationSummary().ToHtmlString()))
```

Comment: Thanks Dima. I'm not sure how to implement that. Currently I have -<div class="valMessages"> @Html.ValidationSummary()</div>, would I replace mine with what you gave me?

Comment: Actually, it will be pretty similar. I have updated answer with this code.

Comment: This worked, Thanks Dima! I had to add "()" to the end of "ToHtmlString". I tried to edit your answer but the correction wasn't enought characters.